# Image not showing in modal on thumbnail click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

When I select a thumbnail from the gallery I want the modal window to pop up and display the image inside. It pops up, but the image isn't displaying, I'm getting the 'alt' message.

Here is my HTML and javascript.

```js
$("#pop").on("click", function () {
    $('#modalPreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').attr('imagesrc'));
    $('#imageModal').modal('show');

});
```

```html
<div id="row">
                <div id="sortable">
                    @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
                    {
                        @*<li>this is an image</li>*@
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                @{
                                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.ImageThumbnail);
                                    var thumbSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
                                    var base64Modal = Convert.ToBase64String(image.Image);
                                    var imgSrcModal = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64Modal);
                                }
                                <a id="pop" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                    <img id="imageresource" src="@thumbSrc" data-imagesrc="@imgSrcModal" alt="image not found" width="203" height="136" />
                                </a>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                                    <p>...</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="imageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                <img id="modalPreview" alt="image not found" width="255" height="255" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

your following line seems incorrect:

```
$('#modalPreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').attr('imagesrc'));
```

get the data attribute, as change to

```
$('#modalPreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').data('imagesrc'));
//or
$('#modalPreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').attr('data-imagesrc'));
```

Comment: yes, thank you. this workded. One question. Is there a better way then this because now I'm loading the src of two images (thumbnail and full image) into the page. Is there a way to dynamically load the full size image only when the call to pop up the modal is made? Or should I set the thumbnail to the full image and just size it down to a thumbnail size? My concern is that this is a gallery and lots of data will be loading on the page if there are multiple images in the gallery.

Comment: @user1186050 you can add source of thumbnail as data attribute like the way you did, that won't load the thumbnail itself… it would be fine..!